# How can I Paste a local file from Windows Explorer to Thunderbird using Ctrl+V?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird, copy-paste, attachments

How can I Paste a local file from Windows Explorer to Thunderbird using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> ?

I know that I can add an attachment in dragging a file from Windows Explorer to Thunderbird and dropping it in an area that is only visible when mouse's cursor dragover. It is very tricky and not userfriendly.

The natural action (for me) is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to select one or more files and to go in message's body to copy all selected files using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Microsoft Outlook do that very very well.

How can I do that in Thunderbird using only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> keys ?

Is there an Thunderbird extension that allows that ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively, Thunderbird doesn't support this functionality.

It does appear to be possible using a Thunderbird add-on named `Attach from Clipboard`.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/attach-from-clipboard/ is a Thunderbird add-on that work using specific key's combination distinct standard Paste/Copy windows key's combination.

Comment: I have installed Attach From Clipboard extension and I can now copy file in attachment using Alt+Shift+V ! Natural Paste/Copy using Ctrl+V doesn't work. This is not perfect but it is more esay than before. I have accepted the solution.

Comment: can you add the name of the extension directly into your answer in replacing Here string by Attach From Clipboard ? Thanks. The hyperlink must not be remove, I propose to replace only the string.